# insert using procedure-null value inserted

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

i have two tables `receipts(rno,r_date,cid)` and `item_list(rno,ordinal,item)`. The rno in the receipts is the primary key. Using a procedure I want to insert a record in the `item_list` with ordinal `value = 1` if the receipt no is not already present. The type of ordinal is number. Here is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insitem (num IN receipts.rno%type, itemid IN item_list.item%type)
IS
CURSOR c2 IS SELECT rno FROM receipts WHERE rno = num;
BEGIN
    OPEN c2;     
    IF c2%notfound THEN
        INSERT INTO item_list VALUES(num, 1, itemid);     
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO item_list VALUES(num, (select MAX(ordinal) FROM item_list WHERE rno = num) + 1, itemid);      
    END IF;
END;
/
```

when I give a new rno as the input the ordinal should be 1 but I get only a null value.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't fetched a value from your cursor, so `notfound` isn't doing what you expect and you are always going into the `else`. This is closer:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insitem (num IN receipts.rno%type,
    itemid IN item_list.item%type)
IS
    CURSOR c2 IS SELECT rno FROM receipts WHERE rno = num;
    l_rno number;
BEGIN
    OPEN c2;    
    FETCH c2 INTO l_rno;
    IF c2%notfound THEN
        INSERT INTO item_list VALUES(num, 1, itemid);     
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO item_list VALUES(num, 
          (select MAX(ordinal) FROM item_list WHERE rno = num) + 1, itemid);      
    END IF;
    CLOSE c2
END;
/
```

But if `rno` is PK in `receipts` and FK in `item_list` then you'll still always go into the `else`, or get a constraint exception. I think you're checking the wrong table, and if so you don't need the cursor really, you could do:

```
INSERT INTO item_list
SELECT num, NVL(MAX(ordinal), 0) + 1, itemid
FROM item_list
WHERE rno = num;
```

But either way way you have the potential for duplicate ordinals if two transactions call this at the same time.

Comment: Thanks a lot man.It worked.I fetched the cursor then tried %notfound.